# How to properly end a gulp task

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to write a gulp task to execute a program and to wait for any key to be pressed to exit the program.

So far I have this:

```
gulp.task('runDevelopment', function (done) {
  console.log('\n\n---\nPress any key to exit\n---\n');

  var api = spawn('node', ['node_modules/api-gateway-server/server.js', 'etc/swagger.yaml']);
  api.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
  api.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  process.stdin.on('data', function () {
    api.kill('SIGKILL');
    done();
  });
});
```

This runs the program, and kills it as expected but gulp never quits. I see this in the console:

```
20:04 $ gulp
[20:06:54] Using gulpfile ~/Development/swiki/gulpfile.js
[20:06:54] Starting 'documentCopy'...
[20:06:54] Starting 'documentZip'...
[20:06:54] Starting 'runDevelopment'...


---
Press any key to exit
---

[20:06:54] Finished 'documentCopy' after 52 ms
[20:06:54] Finished 'documentZip' after 41 ms
[20:06:54] Starting 'package'...
[20:06:54] Finished 'package' after 4.9 μs
API Gateway server listening on port 7111

[20:06:57] Finished 'runDevelopment' after 3.06 s
[20:06:57] Starting 'run'...
[20:06:57] Finished 'run' after 2.72 μs
[20:06:57] Starting 'default'...
[20:06:57] Finished 'default' after 1.16 μs
Terminated: 15
✘-TERM ~/Development/swiki [master|…6] 
20:07 $
```

gulp gives me the `Terminated: 15` only after I `killall gulp` in another terminal.

How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're successfully terminating the child process by sending `SIGKILL`, but you're still listening for incoming data on `process.stdin` of the parent process. As long as you are doing that the parent process won't exit.

You have to explicitly tell `process.stdin` to no longer emit `'data'` events by calling [`stream.pause()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause):

```
process.stdin.on('data', function () {
  process.stdin.pause();
  api.kill('SIGKILL');
  done();
});
```

If all else fails you can also call [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) as a last resort:

```
process.stdin.on('data', function () {
  api.kill('SIGKILL');
  done();
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help:

```js
// Create an task to exit process
gulp.task('finish', () => {
  process.exit();
});

// Add "finish" task to flow
gulp.task('build', [
  'build:1',
  'build:2',
  'build:3',
  'finish'
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).